# Unable to render a Ext.form.TextField into the output of an XTemplate

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to render some Ext components into the output of an `XTemplate`. We want to have the flexibility of using an `XTemplate` to render the HTML but retain the styling, behaviour, and handlers of using Ext components rather than plain old HTML elements.

I am currently successfully doing this with an `Ext.Button`. In the template I am writing a placeholder div like so:
`<div id="paceholder-1"></div>`

After I have called `apply()` on the template I then create a new Ext component and render it in like so:

```
this._replacePlaceholders.defer(1, this, [html, 'placeholder-1', collection]);
```

The `_replacePlaceholders` function looks like this:

```
_replacePlaceholders: function(html, id, collection) {

    var emailField = new Ext.form.TextField({
        emptyText: 'Email address',
        hideLabel: true
    });

    var downloadButton = new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Download as...',
        icon: 'images/down.png',
        scope: this,
        menu: this._createDownloadOptionsMenu(collection) // Create Menu for this Button (works fine)
    });

    var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        items: [emailField, downloadButton]
    });

    downloadButton.render(html, id);
}
```

This works and renders the button into the html correctly. The button menu behaves as expected.

But if I change the last line of `replacePlaceholders` to `emailField.render(html, id);` or `form.render(html, id);` I get a javascript error.

```
TypeError: ct is null
ct.dom.insertBefore(this.el.dom, position);
ext-all-debug.js (line 10978)
```

I'm a bit confused because from what I can tell from the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-render) the `render()` method called is going to be the same one (from `Ext.Component`). But I've had a bit of a play around and can't seem to track down what is happening here.

**So is there any good reason why these components behave differently from `Ext.Button`? and is it possible to render an `Ext.form.TextField` or an `Ext.form.FormPanel` or *anything* that will let me use an Ext text field in mt XTemplate html?**

*NB. I am using ExtJS 3.3.1 and don't have the opportunity to upgrade the version. I believe ExtJS 4 has functionality which would make doing what I doing much easier.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is quite simple - use `form.render(id)` instead of `form.render(html, id)`.

See [api][1] if you have doubts.

The reason why button is rendering properly is that it has weird `onRender` implementation, different from `Component`.

```
onRender : function(ct, position){
    [...]
    if(position){
        btn = this.template.insertBefore(position, targs, true);
    }else{
        btn = this.template.append(ct, targs, true);
    }
    [...]
}
```

As you can see in code above, if you provide position (which is basically second argument provided to `render`) it doen't use `ct` (which is first argument passed to `render`).

In normal component `onRender` method looks like this:

```
onRender : function(ct, position){
    [...]
    if(this.el){
        this.el = Ext.get(this.el);
        if(this.allowDomMove !== false){
            ct.dom.insertBefore(this.el.dom, position);
            if (div) {
                Ext.removeNode(div);
                div = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In code above, you can see, that `ct` is called always, despite the position is not null.

The bottom line is that rendering of button works by accident.

Comment: Thanks Lolo. I didn't realise I never replied to this. Sorry :)